# Are there any tools for viewing a "pass/fail" history of unit tests with respect to SCM commits?

Tags: unit-testing, version-control, continuous-integration

This seems like such a no-brainer that I'm almost *sure* something like this must exist. I just don't know where to find it. On the other hand, maybe there are technical reasons this is impossible, and I'm just not seeing them.

But basically, it seems to me it'd be very helpful if, given a particular unit test, one could (with the assistance of a CI server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)) view a history of commits that affected the red/green status of the test in question. So, say I want to see such a history for unit text X; I might see a history looking like this:

```
Revision | Date       | Test X Status
-------------------------------------
123      | 2011-03-20 | Failed
120      | 2011-03-19 | Passed
119      | 2011-03-19 | Failed
112      | 2011-03-16 | Passed
111      | 2011-03-16 | Pending
```

Hopefully that makes sense: what I'd see would basically be a filtered list of commits—only those that had some effect on the outcome of the particular unit test in question (X).

Does a tool like this exist (*anywhere*—so, as a standalone tool, as a component of some collaboration software, as a plugin for Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

"*Use the **REST**, Luke.*"

This quick and dirty Bash script works with Bamboo, I tested it using Spring Framework [CI server](https://build.springsource.org/rest/api/latest/result) REST API:

```
echo "Revision        Date                            Test X Status"
echo "-------------------------------------------------------------"
url=https://build.springsource.org/rest/api/latest/result
for buildNumber in {1000..980}
do 
    curl -qs ${url}/SPR-TRUNKSNAPSHOT-${buildNumber} \
     | sed 's/^.*state="\(.*\)" key.*buildCompletedTime.\(.*\)..buildCompletedTime.*vcsRevisionKey.\(.*\)..vcsRevisionKey.*$/\3\t\t\2\t\1/'
    echo
done
```

The ugliest part is parsing the XML using `sed` (side note: it's a pity Linux shell does not provide XPath/XSLT built-in command-line tools, *c'mon*, it's XXI century!), but it works:

```
Revision    Date                             Test X Status
-------------------------------------------------------------
4086        2011-03-13T01:09:13.319-08:00    Successful
4083        2011-03-12T01:05:49.145-08:00    Successful
4081        2011-03-11T01:04:46.949-08:00    Successful
4074        2011-03-10T01:09:11.003-08:00    Successful
4069        2011-03-09T01:10:17.766-08:00    Successful
4069        2011-03-08T01:09:34.492-08:00    Successful
4069        2011-03-07T06:43:51.054-08:00    Successful
4068        2011-03-07T03:50:41.909-08:00    Failed
4068        2011-03-07T00:53:55.523-08:00    Failed
4060        2011-03-06T01:06:50.758-08:00    Failed
4060        2011-03-05T01:08:35.477-08:00    Successful
4057        2011-03-04T01:08:52.870-08:00    Successful
4056        2011-03-03T01:10:00.473-08:00    Successful
4056        2011-03-02T01:09:15.679-08:00    Successful
4055        2011-03-01T01:13:19.069-08:00    Successful
4051        2011-02-28T01:08:32.165-08:00    Successful
4050        2011-02-27T00:59:33.392-08:00    Successful
4050        2011-02-26T01:15:01.113-08:00    Successful
4036        2011-02-25T01:09:35.420-08:00    Successful
4032        2011-02-24T01:13:29.997-08:00    Successful
4030        2011-02-23T00:56:51.656-08:00    Failed
```

Jenkins also has [REST](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) support, so it shouldn't take you more than 30 minutes to rewrite my code.